# .Net Maui Navigation Performance, how to improve it?

Tags: c#, android, maui

I’m having an issue with .Net Maui, particularly with navigation where it can be jittery and slow in performance when navigating to a view with a lot of information on, sometimes it can occur even when navigating to a page that only has a collection view with bindings that only load a couple of items.

I have tried with both shell navigation and basic navigation and still the same issue occurs of slow jittery navigation.

The fastest load is when there’s no bindings I have noticed. So is it better to not use bindings for performance? I’ve read the docs on using compiled bindings here [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0) and though it does boost performance it doesn’t fix the issue 100%.

Have tested this on all types of devices from old tablets and phones (6+ years old) to newer tablets and phones (2+ years old). While the newer ones do perform better, the issue is still there.

I’ve seen some suggestions around saying to improve performance you add a Task.Delay(500) to OnAppearing() so that the view can animate in before doing anything but if you were to look at other Android applications made outside of Maui then the pages load within half a second and don’t use this hack, why is Maui different in navigation performance or am I missing something? If anyone knows of a way to improve navigation loading performance let me know.

MonkeysView.xaml

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}">
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                   HeightRequest="60"
                   WidthRequest="60" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Location}"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

MonkeysView.xaml.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<MonkeyModel> Monkeys

public MonkeysView()
{
    BindingContext = this;

}

pubic override void OnAppearing() 
{
    await FetchMonkeysAsync();
}

public async Task FetchMonkeysAsync()
{
    // Simulate monkey fetch
    // Lots of code here to fetch monkeys.
    await Task.Delay(2500);
    // ...
    // ...
    Monkeys = new ObservableCollection<MonkeyModel>(monkeysFromServer);
}
```

MonkeyModel.cs

```
public class MonkeyModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _name;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _location;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _imageUrl;
}
```

Navigate using:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("MonkeysView");
```

Comment: What is your question?  You haven't posted any code illustrating the problem, or any data that validates your assumption that there is a performance issue.

Comment: The question is in the question, why is performance bad in Maui? And it’s not a code issue it’s an issue with any navigation used in Maui.

Comment: You are making the assertion that "performance is bad" without any evidence.  Maybe you are doing something wrong in your code?  I have no idea, because you haven't posted anything.  There are thousands of things that could cause performance issues, how are we to know which one might be involved in your code?

Comment: Have added some code to help you understand how the basic Maui code works whilst omitting some for brevity.

Comment: Have you tried compiled bindings?

Comment: As stated in question have tried as the Microsoft Docs illustrate

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue with any long delay (including access to server) during `OnAppearing`. Try *queueing* the logic to happen after OnAppearing returns: `Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => await FetchMonkeysAsync());` If this helps, then the next refinement is to show a busy/loading indicator while the data loads. ALSO, do any performance test WITHOUT DEBUGGER attached. `Run without Debugging`. OR after downloading, swipe-kill app, and run it again from app icon on Home screen.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it’s not necessarily any long delay with access to server or logic happening, it seems to be more so how the navigation is jittery as the page tries to navigate as well as load a page with a semi complex layout. Fix I’ve found is using await task.Delay(500) as a way to perform navigation and then load the main ui after its navigated

Answer (score 0):

The issue is an internal issue related to the speed at which MAUI renders complex pages. According to the title below, it is planned to be resolved with .Net 8 servicing or .Net 9 at the latest.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14591

Answer (score 0):

This is how I manage slow navigation for complex pages. Currently this solution is tested with an android emulator.

After some testing I found that the last call to trigger before the new page is shown to the user is `OnNavigatedTo` so I do this:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
    await Task.Delay(1);//Yield thread so the page is shown to the user
    //This initial page should mostly just have a spinner
    await VM?.UILoaded();//Load slow complex elements while the user watches the spinner
}
```